# ReactJs Infinite loading scroll pagination keeps loading last page in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am using this package for infinite scroll https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component
But when I scroll down it appears the last page keeps loading on repeat. I passed the following props in the Infinite loading component

```js
<InfiniteScroll  className={classes.card} dataLength={UpcommingSession? UpcommingSession.length: 0} 
            next={()=>dispatch(TecherUpcomingSession({teacherID: teacher._id,page:page+1, limit:10,timezone:time_zone.timezone}))}
             hasMore={true}
             loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}>
```

In next prop I am passing the function that fetches next page, Why does it keep loading last page infinitely? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have `hasMore={true}` in your code, which is the cause of the loop calls.

Try setting the `hasMore` dynamically with help of some state by checking if the limit has reached or if it is the end of the list.
You usually receive these details in the API response.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what you have said is probably right, however I am not able to figure out how to make limit dynamic, can you help me with it if i give you the api detail?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Please share it

Comment: Here is the api https://testingclapingo.herokuapp.com/api/session/teacherupcomingsessionnew 
In body you can put {
    "teacherID":"601a933b7632519c09775c77",
    "page":1,
    "limit":10
}

Comment: Can you provide me with the response in JSON format